# Calling method in generic way

Tags: c#, .net, collections, types

Using this code I get the property of some object by its name:

```
string propName = "Buttons"; // getting this runtime
Type t = container.GetType();
PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty(propName);
object prop = p.GetValue(container, null);
```

the Type of property depends on property name, but all properties have implemented the `IList` interface and therefore all of them have `Add()` method. Now I want to be able to use this method to add elements to that property. But I can't call this method on `object` type. I need somehow to cast it runtime, but before that I have to somehow use `prop.Add()`, which of course triggers a compile error now. Is there any way to call a method at runtime independently of the object type (of course being sure that object has that method).

P.S. if the question isn't clear I can add more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply cast the result to an `IList`?

```
IList prop = (IList)p.GetValue(container, null);
```

You will then get access to `IList` members. Of course, this assumes you are correct in that they are always `IList` otherwise you will start to get `InvalidCastException`s.

---

Alternatively, but I wouldn't advise this, you could always make the assumption that the `Add` method exists and duck-type it using dynamic:

```
dynamic prop = p.GetValue(container, null);
prop.Add("Foo");
```

The above will resolve at runtime using the DLR. It will try to find a public `Add` method that takes a single `string` parameter.

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted, I mean `dynamic` keyword :) I don't have a big experience with .NET so I wasn't even sure is it possible or not

Answer (score 1):

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = t.GetMethod("Add");
result = methodInfo.Invoke(prop, parametersArray);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but Adam's answer suits me more :)